# .NET6 Blazor Server アプリ でサーバ側で更新した値をリアルタイムにWeb表示させたい

Tags: c#

初心者です。
的外れな部分があるかと思いますがよろしくお願いします。

##### 目的

Blazor Server アプリでサーバ側で更新した項目(オブジェクトのプロパティ等)の値をリアルタイムに(ページの更新ではなく)項目の値だけをWebで更新させたい。
(株価ボードのようなイメージ)

#### やったこと

Blazor Server アプリを作成してCountプロパティを持つクラスをタイマークラスで1秒ごとに書き換えたが表示は更新されなかった。

検索で「blazor server サーバーサイド リアルタイム値の自動更新」などキーワードをいくつか変えて検索しましたがそれらしき情報を見つけきれませんでした。
(input bind も試しましたが UI での変更イベントの更新のようで目的の用途に使いきれませんでした)

アドバイスをお願いいたします。

#### 環境

Windows 11 64bit
Visual Studio 2022 v17.1.14
.NET6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問のコメント欄で Blazor は必須かどうか聞いてから回答しようと思ったのですが、どうしても前のアカウントでログインできず、点数不足でコメント欄には書けないので回答欄に書きます。

「サーバ側で更新した値をリアルタイムにWeb表示させたい」ということが目的で、手段は Blazor にこだわらないのであれば ASP.NET Core SignalR を利用することを検討してください。

ASP.NET Core SignalR とは、簡単に言うと、サーバー側のコードでコンテンツを接続されているクライアントに即座にプッシュする機能で、質問者さんの目的に果たすためには有用な手段です。詳しくは以下の記事を見てください。

ASP.NET Core の概要SignalR
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0

> (株価ボードのようなイメージ)

その実装例は以下の記事を見てください。

ASP.NET Core SignalR
http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2021/12/29/aspnet-core-signalr.aspx

Comment: 正にこれです! サンプルも見つけました。ありがとうございました。https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server

Comment: Blazor にも SignalR が実装できるようですね。知りませんでした。

Comment: @WebSurfer 以前のアカウントは [こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/43387/websurfer) でしょうか？アカウントが二つに分かれてしまった場合には、ヘルプを参考にマージすることも可能です。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts